# Sending $(this) on an onchange on the current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
<select class="category" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" onchange="getProducts('standard_product');">
```

and as you can see the onchange calls the getProducts function. I want to know if there is a way to sent in this like

```
<select class="category" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" onchange="getProducts('standard_product', $(this));">
```

which i would hope would be associated to the current select

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to set the value of `this` in your function, you can use `.call`:

```
onchange="getProducts.call(this, 'standard_product');"
```

Now in your getProducts function, `this` will be the element that received the event.

```
function getProducts( prod ) {

    alert( this );  // the <select> element

}
```

You can also pass along the `event` object:

```
onchange="getProducts.call(this, 'standard_product', event);"
```

...and reference it in your function:

```
function getProducts( prod, e ) {

    alert( this );  // the <select> element

    alert( e.type );  // the event type

}
```

---

**EDIT:** As noted by [@Cybernate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527185/cybernate), this is setting the DOM element to `this`. You'll need to wrap it in your `getProducts` function `$(this)`, or set it as such in your inline handler.

Though setting `this` to the element itself is more in line with typical event handler behavior.

---

**EDIT:** To further explain what `.call` does, it allows you to *manually* set the value of `this` in the function you're calling.

Take this function, which simply alerts `this`:

```
function some_func() {

    alert( this );

}
```

Calling it in a basic manner (in a browser) makes `this` reference the DOM Window.

```
some_func();  // the alert will be DOM Window
```

But now lets invoke using `.call`, and setting the first argument to `123`.

```
some_func.call( 123 );  // the alert will be 123
```

You can see that now the alert shows `123`. The function hasn't changed, but the value of `this` has because we've manually set it using `.call`.

If you have additional arguments to send, you just place them after the *thisArg*.

```
function some_func( arg1 ) {

    alert( this );
    alert( arg1 );

}

some_func.call( 123, 456 );
```

The `this` alert will be `123`, and the next argument you send will be set to the `arg1` parameter, so `arg1` will be `456`.

So you can see that `call` basically slices off your first argument you send, sets it as the value of `this`, and sets the remaining arguments as your normal arguments associated with your function parameters.

Comment: @Patrick: +1 , however OP has to change the getProducts method to convert this to $(this) if needed

Comment: @Cybernate: Yes, if that's the case, you're right. I couldn't tell exactly the end result OP was hoping to get.

Comment: thanks again...but what does .call actually do. Does it call the function as it would if i just had onchange="getProducts('....' so it does the same thing but allows me to set the other params

Comment: @Tamer: Yes, but specifically it lets you set the value of `this` in the function you're calling. Because `this` is set by *how* you call the function, this is one way of calling it while *manually* setting the `this` value. The first argument is the *thisArg*. The subsequent arguments are you normal arguments. I'll add another example.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
onchange="function(){var $this = $(this); getProducts('standard_product', $this)}"
```

To make it much better get rid of the inline event handler assignment as below:

```
$(function(){
 $(".category").click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  getProducts('standard_product', $this);
 });
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't need the `var $this` you should just be able to pass `$(this)`.