# Infield calculations using document.getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, input, textfield, calculator

I'm having trouble with my calculation for an infield addition for an input field to take place in two different rows when the user enters an equation the field changes to the answer onChange. Both portions work on their own and I think my issue is with the `document.getElementById` for `document.getElementById("sA"+row).value = result` & `document.getElementById("sB"+row).value = resulta`.

Comment: Your regex code is wrong. You're combining the native syntax with the RegExp constructor, and all you need is the native syntax.

Comment: like this var regex = /(\d+)([+-\/\*])(\d+)/;  ?

Comment: ^ did not resolve if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Basic Fixes

There are many issues in your markup and code, starting with @Pointy's comment regarding your regexp.

In the following, updated, working version, I have commented inline to explain these issues:

```js
function Calculate_Value(row) {
    // NOTE: Settle on the regexp approach to use – i.e. /.../ or
    // new RegExp('...').  Also, your operator character class
    // (i.e. [+-\/\*]), contained unnecessary escaping backslashes
    // (i.e. \/\* instead of /*).  Lastly, even using RegExp objects,
    // there is no need to instantiate two variables for the same
    // pattern to use the pattern against subjectA and subjectB.
    var regex = /(\d+)([+-/*])(\d+)/;

    /*
     * infield calculation for Total subjectA
     */

    // NOTE: There is no need for || 0 below.
    var subjectA = document.getElementById("sA" + row).value; // || 0;
    var found = subjectA.match(regex);
    // NOTE: Simplify your logic by checking whether found === null.
    if (found !== null) {
        var operator = found[2];
        // NOTE: Factor out operand parsing from the + operator's
        // logic because it cuts across matchable operators.
        var first = parseInt(found[1], 10);
        var second = parseInt(found[3], 10);
        // NOTE: Explicitly declare the subjectA result variable for
        // consistency.
        var result;

        // NOTE: Support other matchable operators – i.e. -, /, and
        // * in addition to +.
        if (['+'].indexOf(operator) !== -1) {
            result = first + second;
        } else if (['-'].indexOf(operator) !== -1) {
            result = first - second;
        } else if (['/'].indexOf(operator) !== -1) {
            result = first / second;
        } else if (['*'].indexOf(operator) !== -1) {
            result = first * second;
        } else {
            // Execution should not get here unless logic has not been
            // added above for a newly matchable operator (e.g. %); but
            // let's be defensive.
            result = subjectA;
        }

        // NOTE: Factor out setting the element's value because it
        // cuts across all matches.
        document.getElementById("sA" + row).value = result;
    }

    /*
     * infield calculation for Total subjectB
     */

    // NOTE: There is no need for || 0 below.
    var subjectB = document.getElementById("sB" + row).value; // || 0;
    var founda = subjectB.match(regex);
    // NOTE: Simplify your logic by checking whether founda === null.
    if (founda !== null) {
        var operatora = founda[2];
        // NOTE: Factor out operand parsing from the + operator's
        // logic because it cuts across matchable operators.
        var firsta = parseInt(founda[1], 10);
        var seconda = parseInt(founda[3], 10);
        // NOTE: Explicitly declare the subjectB result variable for
        // consistency.
        var resulta;

        // NOTE: Support other matchable operators – i.e. -, /, and
        // * in addition to +.
        if (['+'].indexOf(operatora) !== -1) {
            resulta = firsta + seconda;
        } else if (['-'].indexOf(operatora) !== -1) {
            resulta = firsta - seconda;
        } else if (['/'].indexOf(operatora) !== -1) {
            resulta = firsta / seconda;
        } else if (['*'].indexOf(operatora) !== -1) {
            resulta = firsta * seconda;
        } else {
            // Execution should not get here unless logic has not been
            // added above for a newly matchable operator (e.g. %); but
            // let's be defensive.
            resulta = subjectB;
        }

        // NOTE: Factor out setting the element's value because it
        // cuts across all matches.
        document.getElementById("sB" + row).value = resulta;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <div class="submit">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <input id="sA1" onchange="Calculate_Value('1');" />
        <!--</div>--> <!-- NOTE: can't close the div mid-td -->
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input id="sB1" onchange="Calculate_Value('1');" />
        <!--</div>--> <!-- NOTE: can't close the div mid-td -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div> <!-- NOTE: new – to finally close the div -->
</table>
```

### Follow-on Considerations

Just because this fixed version works, I would not stop there.  There are at least two glaring smells in the code that remain – work though it does:

1. There is little reason to have duplicate blocks in `Calculate_Value` for `subjectA` and `subjectB`: consider refactoring `Calculate_Value` to just accept a reference to the input element that calls it, which would eliminate *a lot* of duplicate code.  Answers to another SO question, [*Sending $(this) on an onchange on the current element*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6335399/1810429), should give you some ideas how to go about it as a follow-on exercise if you want a version of `Calculate_Value` that honors the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
2. If you do not address the aforementioned remaining smell, at least rename your local variables for clarity.  Appending `a` to all the `subjectA`-related locals for `subjectB`-related logic...is just confusing (i.e. suffix `a` really refers to...`subjectB`).